# Facebook: What does "seen" in message dialog exactly mean?

Tags: facebook

Sometimes I write messages to some chicks I don't know personally and they are no friends of friends of mine. Few minutes after I wrote a message, I see a "seen: 8:24" below my message. I can't believe that the receiver chick already read my message few minutes after I sent it. Another important information (for the next example) is, that this receiver is in the same Facebook group as me. I figured out that a receiver which is not a friend or a friend of friend of mine see my message as incoming mark on top bar when she is in the same group. Otherwise the receiver wouldn't see the message as incoming mark.

Another example: Some months ago I wrote another chick which was not in the same group as me so she probably never saw my message (because it's not marked as incoming). Despite that there was a "seen" at the same day. It's improbable that she really **read** my message. 
So what does "seen" exactly mean? Is it just a confirmation of receipt. I doubt that the receiver really **read** the message or opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

technically that 'seen' means, the message thread has been clicked/opened. You can actually read a part of the message by clicking it in the message notification overview without being mark as 'seen'

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, *seen* means that the message has been seen, or acknowledged, by the recipient.

Now, keep in mind that there are some applications that provide an interface for different chat engines, including facebook. I have not tested this yet, but it is possible that facebook would perceive it as *seen* when the application receives the message and delivers it to the user.